# How to hide microvias when working on separate layers in KiCAD 5.1.10?

Tags: kicad, via

If you have a PCB with microvias on completely separate layers, i.e. 1-2 and 5-6, when working on layers other than 1 & 2, is there a way to hide these vias so they do not obscure the viewport for other layers?

I noticed in the Layers Manager there is no option specifically for microvias, however, there is an option to hide "Through Via". This works great for Through-hole vias as they completely disappear. But, through-hole vias are obviously something you need to account for at all layers. And for microvias, this option only hides the inside shaded region of the via as shown below.

Before hiding:
[image: before]

After hiding:
[image]

I haven't been able to figure out how to remove microvias when working on other layers, and I'm also unsure even what material these teal circles are representing. Is this simply a currently unimplemented feature, and if so has the recent KiCAD 6.0 version release allowed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Hidden Layers]
Like other elements, you can hid the microvias by hiding the layers on which they are present.  So, if your microvia is on F.Cu and In2.Cu (layers 1-2), you can hide both of those layers to hide your microvia.

[image: High Contrast button]
Alternatively, you can use "High Contrast" mode to dim layers that are not active and this will make the microvias grey when you are not on their layers.

Comment: On version 6, activating High Contrast twice (pressing `H` on default keybindings) actually hides the other layers completely. So it's now a tri-state (normal-dim-hide).